# Regex match against block of text

Tags: regex

I'm having one of those moments where I can't think of the right syntax for my regex.

I've got a block of text like below

```
config lines
config lines
config lines
config lines
config lines
interface ethernet0/0
 description "my interface"
 ip address 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255
 service-policy output my-service-policy
config lines
config lines
config lines
config lines
```

The match I am trying to make is that interface ethernet0/0 is present, and the 'service policy output my-service-policy' exists, but having trouble matching the first and last lines in one regex.

Comment: What is the regex you have tried, and how did it come up short?

Answer (score 0):

In which language are you coding?

Generally you can access the first beginning of a String / the beginning of each line in a multi-line pattern via the ^ sign.

Is it copied right, that the request line begins with a white space? Then you simply can get those with p.E. in PHP: $result = preg_match('/^\s/');

Answer (score 0):

I would use;

```
/(ethernet0\/0|\sservice-policy output my-service-policy)/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/wC6fI9/2